# Google Chrome cancel up and down arrow events

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, safari, dom-events, event-bubbling

I'm making an AutoSuggest widget for a website, which works in the way that when an user writes something in input text box the div with suggestions is displayed and an user can navigate through it by mouse or by up and down arrows. Each word is suggested separately (not like in Google suggest where it looks on the whole phrase.

I have a problem with Google Chrome input box as when I'm pressing up or down arrow there is a default behaviour of browser - jump with carret to the end or beginning of the text box (like with Home or End buttons). There is no such effect on Firefox or Internet Explorer. How could I disable this effect?

I'm returning 'false' from the event handler function and also used a function from here http://www.javascripter.net/faq/canceleventbubbling.htm but still carret is jumping on Chrome...

Edit: same effect on Safari...

Comment: I have the same problem when writing a autosuggest one year ago...

Comment: I've noticed that there is a same behaviour with Safari so it's a WebKit way of working -.-
Also found that to get this work as I want user have to use ctrl+down or up...

Comment: Are you using jQuery? Either way, try catching `keydown`, `keyup` and `keypress` with `return false;` for each, and put your navigation code within your `keydown` handler before returning.

Comment: nope, Im canceling every key-related event but still jumping of the carret exsits, I supose that this is not driven by the event but some kind of internal browser behaviour ;/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exatly a true solution for a question but I've done a workaround by using this functions
http://blog.vishalon.net/index.php/javascript-getting-and-setting-caret-position-in-textarea/
and catching the carret position before event (or not exatly before as when keydown event is fired the carret is still on good position) and then setting it back after event.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried preventing the default behavior?

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  ...
}, false);
```

Comment: Im not using jQuery but still I supose it would not work as this is not a event behaviour. I've done this in a way that when keydown is fired the caret is still on good position, so I can store the position and after jump get it back.